# Does NSFileHandle create the sockets for me?

Tags: iphone, sockets, ipad, networking, nsfilehandle

Does NSFileHandle create the sockets for me? Or must I create them myself and then setup an NSFileHandle to use that socket?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it does not. Use `initWithFileDescriptor:` initializer and supply a BSD socket. These are real basics, it's all written in documentation, please consult the documentation before posting here.

Comment: I did read the whole Low Level File Management Programming Topics guide. And they don't talk much about details there.